# Datetime to Time/HH:MM format – investigating events on multiple dates by the time of day

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, timestamp

I have a pandas dataframe with a column "Datetime" which has values in pd.Timestamp / np.datetime64 format. How should I extract the hours and minutes while keeping the status of this "HH:MM" as "continuous plottable values?"

I want to plot a histogram of the dataframe column (pd.Series) based on the frequency in "HH:MM sense" in which case the x-axis would range from 00:00 to 23:59 etc.

```py
import pandas as pd
# ...
new_df["Datetime"][0]
> Timestamp('2022-08-08 16:58:00')
```

I saw examples of extracting the time as a string. Not good enough. I could also use groupby hour and then e.g. plot a bar chart by count but that's not exactly what I was looking for, either...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

...or I could convert each row to a string and then immediately back to pd.Timestamp with the same date. It's not ideal, but works. Any better ideas?

I battled with this a bit longer and got it working decently. Is this really the most straightforward way of doing it? The lambda stuff feels always a bit far-fetched, and this one still keeps the full date which isn't a problem per se but not necessary, either (and requires extra formatting on the xaxis).

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.dates as mdates

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
plt.xticks(rotation=45)
ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(mdates.DateFormatter('%H:%M'))

# pd.Timestamp convers the date automatically to "today" if YYYYMMDD is not specified
new_df["Datetime"].apply(lambda t:pd.Timestamp(f'{t.hour:02d}:{t.minute:02d}')).hist(ax=ax)
```

[image]